# How to validate Office 365 group id (email alias) availability using Microsoft graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Office 365 Admin portal checks for Group Id (email alias) availability during creation of the group. How I can perform such check using Microsoft Graph?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry - this API is not available through Microsoft Graph yet.  Please request this feature through [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis).

Hope this helps,